# Implementation of Dirichlet-Neumann method

Tags: differential-equations, numerics, parallelization, finite-element-method

I am new in Mathematica and I was trying to find documentation on the Dirichlet-Neumann and Neumann-Neumann methods (which are part of Domain Decomposition Method), but I couldn't find any. Can someone help me on implementation of this type of algorithm?

Comment: You will greatly increase your chances of getting help here if you were to put more effort into your question. Make the question specific. "Help me with ..." or something similar is never well-received. If you have code that is not giving the results you want, show the code and describe exactly what you expected to get but didn't. If you don't know how to start coding what you want, describe your problem carefully in words giving the full set of inputs you would provide and what output you expect to get back.

Answer (score 2):

There is a package called [FEMAddons](https://github.com/WolframResearch/FEMAddOns) that provides utilities that may be of help when implementing domain decomposition methods, and there is an article using it [here](http://wolframlanguagereviews.org/2018/08/09/domain-decomposition-method-using-graph-coloring/).

AFAIK, Neumann-Neumann and Dirichlet-Neumann methods cannot be implemented because to implement them you need to be able to enforce boundary conditions such as

$$
\partial_{n_1}u_1=\partial_{n_2}u_2,
$$

where $n_i$, to paraphrase [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neumann%E2%80%93Neumann_methods), is the unit normal vector to the boundary shared by the subdomains $u_1$ and $u_2$. If you look at `NeumannValue`, you will see that it allows you to specify boundary conditions of the type

$$
\overset{\rightharpoonup}{n}\cdot (c \nabla u - \gamma + \alpha \
u) = g - q u,
$$

where the constants are defined implicitly by the PDE. However, from what I understand, enforcing, in general, the Neumann-Neumann boundary condition stated above is not possible.

(Always happy to be corrected though.)